# How to change the @Model in a partial view in ASP.NET 5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I need help to make a partial view. I created a partial view and I want to change model in it. In addition, I would like my partial view to be controlled by a controller.

I don't understand why it's not Ok.

Here is the markup of the view :

```
<select asp-for="Categorie" id="categorie">
    <script>
        $('#categorie').load('/Home/BudgetSearch');
    </script>
</select>
```

Here is my controller :

```
public IActionResult BudgetSearch()
{
        //var bdd = new ComptesBudgetViewModel();

        var query = _context.Budget.Select(oa => oa.Categorie).Distinct();

        return PartialView("BudgetSearch", query.ToList());
}
```

Here is the code of my partial view :

```
@model Comptes.core.data.Models.Budget

<option value="" selected>Choisir</option>
@foreach (var budget in Model.Categorie)
{
    <option value="@budget">@budget</option>
}
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: You're not very clear on whether you're using the full, classic **ASP.NET MVC** (on the full .NET Framework) - or the new cross-platform **ASP.NET Core** (and the MVC stack on that). Please be precise and accurate in telling us what you're using!

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET, The last one : not .net core and not .net framework

Comment: ASP.NET **is** on the .NET Framework - the "full", classic .NET (up to v4.8) - removed the `asp.net-core` tag

Comment: the model required by your partial view is not a list, it's a `Budget`, so this `PartialView("BudgetSearch", query.ToList())` would cause exception at runtime. If you want it to be a list of `Budget`, the model should be changed to something like `@model IList<Comptes.core.data.Models.Budget>`

Comment: It's a good thing but I have a problem before.
The controller doesn't redirect to the partial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your badget has a Category property, change your code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Comptes.core.data.Models.Categorie>

<option value="" selected>Choisir</option>
@foreach (var category in @Model)
{
    <option value="@category.Name">@category.Name</option>
}
```

and maybe you need to change your action:

```
public IActionResult BudgetSearch()
{
        //var bdd = new ComptesBudgetViewModel();

        var query = _context.Set<Categorie>().ToList()

        return PartialView("BudgetSearch", query);
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was searching for !
Thanks you very much